# How do I retrieve my bitcoin balance?

Tags: wallet, spending

I have a bitcoin balance. What's the process I need to follow to spend my balance in my bitcoin address?

Answer (score 2):

- Navigate to the 'send' page in the wallet
- Paste in your recipient's address into the 'send to' field (and perform a double check that the pasted address is the same as the address you copied. Do the first 5-6 and last 5-6 characters all match?)
- Input the amount to be sent (specify this to the satoshi, for better privacy)
- As your wallet allows: select the transaction fee-rate, UTXO(s) to be used as input, and write yourself a memo so that you can later remember what the transaction was about.
- Double check all the fields (there are no take-backs once a transaction is broadcast!), and then confirm the send.